# want to store pairs of int values and compare then

Tags: java

I have data in a form of pairs of values (e.g. (0,2), (2, 6), (6,0)).  I want to do some comparisions on each pair (e.g. if I have a value of 3 is it between a given pair of values).  What is the best way to store these values and be able to perform such comparision?

Thank you

Comment: _if I have a value of 3 is it between a given pair of values_ Didn't get this

Comment: I'd assume, 3 is not between (0 and 2) or (6 and 0), but it is between (2 and 6)?

Comment: @ziesemer - Are you sure 3 isn't between 6 and 0?

Comment: @rfeak - No, I'm not.  The requirements aren't sure enough to say for sure.

Comment: 3 would be between 0 and 6 yes but I also want to take into account that it is between 6 and 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the values as a list/collection of tuples, two-element arrays, or an [`IntRange` (docs)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html), or...

The comparison itself presents a few options; you could just compare manually and return true/false if in-range/out-of-range. Or you could implement `Comparable` and compare to a single value, returning -1, 0, 1 for below-lowest-value, in-range, above-highest-value, respectively, use a tuple/range class's `contains`-like method, or...

It depends a bit on what you're actually trying to do, but roughly, using `IntRange`:

```
List<IntRange> ranges = new ArrayList<IntRange>() {{
    add(new IntRange(0, 2));
    add(new IntRange(2, 6));
    add(new IntRange(6, 0));
}};

public boolean inRange(int n, List<IntRange> ranges) {
    for (IntRange range : ranges) {
        if (range.containsInteger(n)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You also need to decide what to do about "reversed ranges" like `6..0`.

Comment: Yes I want to count them too (i.e. 3 would be a value I would like to take into account if a pair is (6,0)).

Answer (score 2):

Create a class, specifically dedicated to this purpose.

```
public class Pair
{
  final int first;
  final int second;

  public Pair ( int first, int second )
  {
    // perform some validation that first is less than second
    ...
  }

  public boolean isValueInBetween( int value )
  {
     retrn value >= first && value <= second;
  }
}
```

Here is usage:

```
Pair one( 0, 2);
Pair two( 2, 6);
Pair three( 0, 6);

System.out.println( one.isValueInBetween( 3 ) );
System.out.println( two.isValueInBetween( 3 ) );
System.out.println( three.isValueInBetween( 3 ) );
```